# rtabmap localization issue

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, obstacle-avoidance, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am facing one issue during localization in rtabmap. When there is an dynamic obstacle in front of the robot an even during the navigation time map data gets some times disappears on rviz and the robot gets delocalized. Why this happens so? What is the solution for this so that there is continuous update of map from rtabmap? Please suggest as soon as possible. Thanks.

EDIT:

1. map_with_rviz.png

[C:\fakepath\map_with_rviz.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864792696605739.png)
[image description http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864792696605739.png](http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864792696605739.png)

2. map_with_obstacle.png

[C:\fakepath\map_with_obstacle.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864793381481581.png)
[image description http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864793381481581.png](http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864793381481581.png)

3. disappear_map_with_obstacle.png

[C:\fakepath\map_with_delocalize.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794041882759.png)
[image description http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794041882759.png](http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794041882759.png)

4. disappear_map_with_obstacle_1.png

[C:\fakepath\map_with_delocalize_1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794378132744.png)
[image description http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794378132744.png](http://answers.ros.orghttps://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14864794378132744.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253888/rtabmap-localization-issue/) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-07**:
Please don't link to images on cloud services, attach them to this post.

Please do this as soon as possible. Thanks.

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2017-02-07**:
Thanks for suggestion I attached the screenshots.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-02-07**:
What happens between 2 and 3? Robot moved?

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2017-02-08**:
Hello In 2nd image as you can see the the robot initial position as /base_link (frame ) when we give goal to the robot behind the Obstacle , the robot while avoiding the obstacle it loses its Global_map as in the 3rd image the /global_map has disappear , why this happens so please can you suggest me

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2017-02-08**:
Also the local_map changes its behavior when the global_map gets disappear as seen in Image 3rd

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-02-08**:
the local costmap should not change if the global map changes. Make sure your local costmap is in /odom frame, not /map frame. What is your fixed frame in RVIZ?

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2017-02-08**:
Okay,and My fixed frame on rviz is /map frame

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-02-09**:
What is the output on the terminal where rtabmap is launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During localization, the map should not disappear even if the camera is obstructed. Do you refer to move_base local costmap or the grid_map published by rtabmap? In localization mode, rtabmap doesn't update the map. It may add current  seen obstacles but they should disappear if the obstacle is not anymore in the field of view of the sensor. If you have screenshots, it may help to see the problem.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0